# I'm having trouble with the table that I imported into R from Fangraphs

Tags: r, web-scraping

I want to scrape a table from Fangraphs, a baseball statistics website. Here's the link to the table I'd like to use:

https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=0&type=8&season=2023&month=0&season1=2023&ind=0&team=0,ts&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0

My problem is when I import the table from Fangraphs, it doesn't look quite right and I'm not sure what to do.

Here's the code I ran to read in the proper table:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url = "https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=0&type=8&season=2023&month=0&season1=2023&ind=0&team=0,ts&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0"

p = url %>% read_html %>% html_nodes("table")

era <- url %>% read_html %>% html_nodes("table") %>% .[9] %>% html_table(trim = T)

view(era)
```

Which then produces the troubled graph, which I've posted an image of [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xsf0u.png).

As you can see, the column names are just X's with some number after them, and the real column names (team name, W, L, etc.) are just regular rows. Any idea on how to fix this issue, whether it be by cleaning it or importing it differently?